# Cloning and then cropping an image using System.Drawing.Rectangle returns 'out of memory' exception

Tags: c#, bitmap, system.drawing

I am trying to **crop the bottom 25%** of an image but I am getting an 'out of memory' exception. I know from testing in my code and research that this exception is purely being thrown due to my coordinates being out of range.

I have an image called bmp which is 400px in width and 250px in height. I am cropping it with the following code...

```
PixelFormat = bmp.PixelFormat;
Bitmap CroppedImage = bmp.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 250, 400, 62), bmpFormat);
```

This gives me: 'Exception Details: System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.'

However, if my code was written...

```
PixelFormat = bmp.PixelFormat;
Bitmap CroppedImage = bmp.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 62), bmpFormat);
```

my image is cropped from the top left downwards (i.e. I am getting the top 25%) which to me makes no sense to me as surely I would need to have the height set as -62 not 62 to do this.

If somebody could point me towards an answer on this that would be superb!

Comment: It's not clear from your question what it is you actually expect to happen when you pass out-of-range coordinates, or why that's relevant. The lack of a good [mcve] exacerbates this lack of clarity. But, it sounds a little like you are under the misimpression that the bitmap coordinate system puts the origin at the bottom left of the image. This is not the case, not for standard bitmaps in the .NET context. The origin is the top left, with Y coordinates increasing in value downward. If that's not enough to get you back on track, you will need to improve your question considerably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind that first two arguments in `Rectangle`'s constructor are coordinates of the upper left corner of the rectangle. This makes rectangle's upper right corner being at `(650, 0)` going over image's `400` width in your first example. Therefore exception.

In your second example, rectangle covers original image along its width but its height is only 62 pixels - therefore you see only that upper part of the image cropped.

Also, note that `y` axis is not placed like in classical geometry. Here `y` axis points "down".

Comment: The x-axis does not point down, it is horizontal as normal.  The y-axis points down, the inevitable side-effect of having (0,0) at the upper-left.  The rectangle's upper-right corner is at (400,0).

Comment: @HansPassant You're absolutely correct. I edited my answer.